# How can I read Excel file row by row and send email to the names on the worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, outlook

We have an Excel file called *empList.xlsx* with a list of users whose servers are very close to running out of space.

The email is intended to advise users of the current space status and to delete some files to free up some space.

The VB script below only reads employees' email addresses and sends them email notifications but doesn't read the rest of the data on a particular row.

```vb
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Function getEmail()
    Dim iCol As Integer, iRow As Integer
    Dim sEmailBody As String
    Dim sEmailTo as string ' the recipient
    iCol = 1 ' column A
    iRow = 2 ' row 2

    Do
        sEmailTo = cells(irow, 1).text
        sEmailBody = sendData(iRow)
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Loop While Not Len(Trim(Cells(iRow, iCol))) = 0
End Function

Function sendData(ByVal iRow As Integer) As String
    Dim iCol As Integer

    For iCol = 2 To 11 ' B=2, K=11
        sendData = sendData & Cells(iRow, iCol).Text & vbCrLf
    Next

    MsgBox sendData
End Function

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
set objConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open _
   ("C:\Logs\EmpList.xlsx")

Set objFlds = objConf.Fields
With objFlds
  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtprey.domain.com"
  .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
  '.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = cdoAnonymous
  .Update
End With
Set objEmail.Configuration = objConf
x = 2
Do Until objExcel.Cells(x, 2).Value = ""
    Set objEmail.Configuration = objConf

    objEmail.From = "noReply@domain.com"
    objEmail.To = objExcel.Cells(x, 2)
    objEmail.Subject = "Your H Drive is Full"
    objEmail.Textbody = sendData(2)
    objEmail.Send
    x = x + 1
Loop
objExcel.Quit
```

Below is an example of how each row is laid out:

```
Jim.Brown@domain.com|H:\home\matt.tavakolian\|60.3 GB|54629.5 GB|2274|288|0.0 GB| 6.7%|3/4/2013 3:11 PM|3/11/2013 12:16 PM|9/23/2008 3:26 PM
```

Since I don't know of a way to add an attachment, I have used pipes (|) to indicate data on each cell per row.

The example above example represents row #2 from CellA to CellK.

What we would like to do is send an email to say, Jim.Brown@domain.com on row #2 and include all data on that row (from CellA to CellK) to show the current server hard drive space.

Is this possible?

Comment: when referencing Cells, may need to explicitly reference the Excel Object, workbook, and activeworksheet since the OP is using OLE Automation from VBScript in MS Outlook

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this (using the Excel object and workbook object obviously):

```
Function getEmail()

Dim iCol As Integer, iRow As Integer
Dim sEmailBody As String
Dim sEmailTo as string ' the recipient
iCol = 1 ' column A
iRow = 2 ' row 2

Do
    sEmailTo=cells(irow,1).text
    sEmailBody = sendData(iRow)
    iRow = iRow + 1
Loop While Not Len(Trim(Cells(iRow, iCol))) = 0

End Function
```

in that function you call the below function to get the email body!

```
Function sendData(ByVal iRow As Integer) As String

Dim iCol As Integer

For iCol = 2 To 11 ' B=2, K=11
    sendData = sendData & Cells(iRow, iCol).Text & vbCrLf
Next

    MsgBox sendData

End Function
```

so just call the function 'getEmaily' to get the email address and the body that goes into your email body!

HTH

Philip

Comment: Thanks @Philip,

Does your function need to be separate from the script I posted?

Comment: you could use something like **objEmail.Textbody = sendData(2)** for row 2

Comment: Thanks Philip but your solution got me totally confused.

Does it mean that the code I posted earlier is to be thrashed?

I don't mind doing that but I can't make much sense of your proposed solution.

Comment: No not at all, just include my code in your module, and call the functions to get the extra data like I say above

Comment: OK, @Philip, I have updated my code above to include yours. As I stated, I am still confused as to *how* to integrate them as I am getting all kinds of errors.

Sorry if I am too slow in catching what you are trying to do.

Comment: what errors are you getting, on what line? Don't forget you have to reference the Excel application, workbook, and worksheet object to get to the Cells object...

Comment: I have just modified your code, I think you need something like: **objExcel.activeworkbook.activeworksheet.Cells**

Comment: Hi @Philip, you must be a .net developer. Some of your syntaces are of .net flavor like ByVal iRow as Integer)... or like this line:

sendData = sendData & Cells(iRow, iCol).Text & vbCrLf, '(iRow,iCol).Text'

Can you please change them to vbscript.

This is problem with the functions.

Comment: Those are from Visual Basic 6 and VBA in Excel, Access, Word, Powerpoint...as you are using VBScript in MS Outlook, you change them to sendData(iRow), and you change **Dim x as y** to **Dim x** (examples)

Comment: for help with VBScript, add the tag VBScript to your question, or ask the question on the VBScript area

Comment: and here are the [VBScript References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt(v=vs.84).aspx) and [MSDN Scripting Clinic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg581726.aspx) and [MSDN - Outlook development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa167881(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: There is a vbscript tag in my original question. Quite frankly, I don't mind using your code as is but where do I put it inside excel? I have seen a lot changes made to my original code and I TRULY appreciate those changes but I am not sure if the changes reflect that the code is now vbscript?

And how do I change this line to vbscript?

`sendData = sendData & Cells(iRow, iCol).Text & vbCrLf'

Comment: Are you programming for MS Outlook, or for a VBScript file. Outlook has VBA support so that code should work. My code doesn't need to run inside Excel, you sould be able to run that code against your excel object created using CreateObject method in your script

Comment: This is for Excel file, not outlook

Comment: yeah I get that, but if it was for Excel, why not write a VBA macro inside the Excel VB Editor (open Excel, and then use **ALT+F11** to open the VB Editor

Comment: They want to schedule the script the send email weekly and I am a bit ok with vbscript but not vba.

Comment: ok, in that case you'll have to research a little more on [W3Schools.com - using functions in VB Script](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_procedures.asp) and [W3Schools - VBScript Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/default.asp)

Comment: But the answer I gave should be what you need